# ASP.NET MVC Routing question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have simple question about MVC routing. How i can construct Html.ActionLink thhat generates following link http://mysite.com/phones/samsung
Now it's generates as http://mysite.com/phones/brand?brand=samsung
Also i want to avoid mentioning action name in URL
There is my code:

Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "Phones/{brand}", 
new { controller = "Phones", action = "Index", brand = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Controller:

```
MySyteDBEntities ms = new MySyteDBEntities();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Brand = ms.Phones.Select(x => x.Brand).Distinct();
    return View();            
}

public ActionResult Brand(string brand)
{
    ViewBag.Standard = ms.Phones.Where(x => x.Brand == brand).Select(x => x.Standard).Distinct();
        return View();
}
```

Index View code:

```
@foreach (string item in ViewBag.Brand)
{                    
    <div>@Html.ActionLink(item, "Brand", new { brand = item })</div>
}
```

Comment: The second token is called brand in the MapRoute.   In the actionlink it was called category.   If you call it the same in both places it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your MapRoute you have no space for an action, so asp.net will always use the default action "Index".

By default your routing would look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(" Default", "{controller}"/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

You're missing the action part.

Routevalues in you actionlink which don't match parameters in your route, will be querystring parameters. So you need to change "category" to " brand" in your route.

Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "Phones/{brand}", 
 new { controller = "Phones", action = "Index", brand = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

and

```
@foreach (string item in ViewBag.Brand)
{                    
 <div>@Html.ActionLink(item, "Index", "Phones", new { brand = item }, null)</div>
}
```

Be sure to call the controller explicit in your ActionLink, if the current view is mapped through another route, otherwise it doesn't recognize the `brand` parameter.

Comment: Hi Andrew! Thanks for comment. I missed to change variables names. So my code looks same as you proposed, and links that generated: http://mysite.com/phones/brand?brand=samsung  instead of  http://mysite.com/phones/samsung

Comment: @Sergey I guess you didn't solve your problem yet. Try using the next overload:  `@Html.ActionLink("PhoneHome", "Index", "Phones", new { brand = "Samsung" }, null)` 

Because you did not explicit specified an controller in your ActionLink MVC maps it to the current controller of the View. My guess is that the current view is not mapped with your new route, so doesn't recognize the `brand` parameter

Answer (score 1):

Try (this route should be registered before the default route, if you have one)

```
        routes.MapRoute(
         "Phones", // Route name
         "Phones/{[^(Index)]brand}", // URL with parameters
         new { controller = "Phones", action = "Brand", brand = "" } // Parameter defaults
     );
```

With this, http://mysite.com/phones/ --> should go to Index Action and
http://mysite.com/phones/samsung --> should go to the Brand Action.

Answer (score 1):

i'm found source of problem. I just need to remove last piece (brand optional parameter) in MapRoute. Hare is code:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "Phones/{brand}", new { controller = "Phones", action = "Brand" });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "Phones/{id}", 
new { controller = "Phones", action = "Index", id= UrlParameter.Optional })

public ActionResult Brand(string id)
{
    ViewBag.Standard = ms.Phones.Where(x => x.Brand == brand).Select(x => x.Standard).Distinct();
        return View();
}
```

By using id as the parameter name, it will prevent the routing from using the querystring key value pairs.

Your parameterless GET and View code should still work without any changes.

Comment: Thanks Scott, changing variable name to id helps, but i still see path with controller name in it, can i avoid this?

Comment: Also what about two variable that passed to controller? there only one variable can be called id

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the {brand} part needs to be included as is as part of your parameters:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "Phones/{brand}", 
new { controller = "Phones", action = "Index", brand = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Just remember, it needs to go before any default routes.